# How to disable PIN lock in android device without touching it

Tags: lock-screens, touchscreen, broken-screen, sony-xperia-z2

My android phone *(Sony Xperia Z2)* has a PIN lock, and now the screen is broken, everything is working fine **except touch**, I can't do anything because I can't unlock the phone because I can't press the buttons to unlock it. So is there a way I can unlock the phone with? Even if the touch isn't working I can use the phone with Google Assistant.

PS: My phone doesn't have root.

Comment: Hi! Have you gone through the resources under the tag [tag:broken-screen]? Let us know what worked or didn't work for you.

Comment: yah, but I didn't find anything helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So when you say broken screen, but then "everything is working except touch", does the display work?

Below I've written a solution that'll work with a broken display and touch, if your display does work, then just use an OTG adapter and a mouse, if not follow the steps below.

- Get an OTG adapter with a mouse
- Make a screenshot (probably power + vol down)
- Connect your phone to your PC and view what's in view what's in /sdcard/DCIM/Screenshots/
- Continue doing that to go into Settings > Developer Options and enable USB Debugging (it's painful, but the only way)
- After you've done that you can use [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) to mirror your screen to your PC via adb and interact with it. (The first time you use your PC with adb you'll get a prompt to authenticate on the phone you'll have to click allow there, just keep that in mind)

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't have OTG adapter, but fortunately Debugging mode was enabled (because use my phone in Android Studio).